# Asynchronus way of image in for loop

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, ios5, ios6

I have an for loop , which consists of uiimageview inside it, everytime i add the image from the array which consits of url , i convert it to data and imagewithdata method am using it, it works for me perfectly but it takes long time , can we acheive it in lazy loading which is used in uitableview?

Pls help

Thanks in advance

Comment: chk this may be it help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18486108/how-to-avoid-delay-when-adding-more-than-one-button-to-scrollview-in-iphone/18486398#18486398

Comment: @KSR Please add your code. Also, there are plenty of questions on SO for lazy loading of images in `UITableView`, search well before asking duplicate questions.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of Lazzy Loading I used following way in UItableView and its working for me without scrolling issue .

```
 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^(void) {

            NSData *imageData ;

            imageData = [UICommonUtils imageDataFromString:profile.Photo];

            dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void) {


                    if([imageData length] > 1)
                    {
                        //UIImageView* imageView = (UIImageView*)[cell viewWithTag:100];
                        cell.ProfileImage.image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        cell.ProfileImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:kDefaultProfileImage];
                    }

                });

            imageData = nil;
        });
```

Comment: but i use inside for loop , will it work in for loop perfectly ?

Comment: Try it is your code, because without for loop its working,I didnt need to use for loop because my each table cell contain on only image at that time.

Comment: @KSR it will wrk for for loop also

Comment: @KSR I note one thing You already posted this query, then why are you post it again ?? here is your previous post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18461699/asynchronus-for-loop-in-iphone

Comment: @aman its getting crashed  in for loop ,if i try to using the following code...